# Can question on SAP ERP be asked here?

Tags: support

I was interested in knowing whether questions on SAP MM module or others modules can be asked on this site

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: You mean the main site, not here specifically on meta, right? This site is for questions about the main site, not for programming questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard have asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419745/issue-of-missing-service-lines-in-sap-mm-pr

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd say that as long as your question is programming related, feel free to ask your question. If it isn't appropriate, the community will be quick to let you know.

But be aware that for extremely localized questions in that they require very narrow expertise to get a good answer, Stack Overflow might not be the best place to post. In those cases, it's usually better to turn to the community dealing with that specific technology. If there is one, that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can, I there are other `ERP` systems, like `JD Edwards`, that have questions on SO.  However the community is extremely under represented on SO that you probably will not get any quality answers.  The best bet for these answers are vendor specific forums and communities.